# rails console test loading development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem where

```
rails console test
```

results in

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)
```

I suspect it's a `RAILS_ENV` problem because doing

```
RAILS_ENV=test rails console
```

results in

```
Loading test environment (Rails 3.1.0)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you must specify `RAILS_ENV` or use `rails console [environment]`.

Comment: Then what's the purpose of `rails console test`?

Comment: I don't think it exists.  There is, however a `--sandbox` option which allows you to run the rails console w/o changing data for that environment.  I _think_ you can pass test to dbconsole (`rails dbconsole test`) to get into the test database.

Comment: Or, maybe I'm wrong...  I just ran `rails c test` on a project & found: `Loading test environment (Rails 3.1.0)`

Comment: But I'm still lost as to why `rails console test` doesn't work for me =/

Comment: Not sure. @Brian confirms working with Rails 3.1.0, and I can confirm it working with 3.0.9.. It must be something particular to you.. unfortunately.. you could always alias something to `RAILS_ENV="test" rails console`..

Comment: But this answer says one may do `rails console [environment]` to bring up the Rails console, in the test environment. That's just what the OP did!—and it failed for him. So this answer should not be accepted.

Comment: @MarkDBlackwell, suggesting the original poster reject a previously accepted answer just to accept your own answer is generally considered poor form. I'm assuming that my answer aided him in some way, because if it didn't, he wouldn't have accepted it.

Comment: @Adam-Eberlin, my purpose wasn't as you describe! It's difficult to see how that prong of your accepted answer aided him, because he included it in his question, you see. It seems he was asking why the difference. If it's poor form, I don't feel as competitive as you, perhaps. ;/ BTW, Axsuul, why did you accept that answer?

Comment: How will this answer aid any other StackOverflow users who share the OP's setup problem (if that's what's causing it)?

Answer (score 1):

Is environment variable RAILS_ENV already set (in your command line environment)?

Ideally, `rails console test` should set RAILS_ENV to 'test' and disregard its value in the command line environment.

However, if it is set to something (nonblank) other than 'test', then, obviously, potentially one might see a difference in behavior between `rails console test` and `RAILS_ENV=test rails console`.

EDIT: If RAILS_ENV is set to development in my shell environment, and I do `rails console test`, then I get the test environment, just as Adam Eberlin and Brian also report.

It's still mysterious (to me) what might be different in your setup, or what's causing your observed difference in behavior.

Therefore, you should not accept this (my) answer!