# RSpec mock from test console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test out RSpec stubbing and mocking from a rails test console . Is it possible ? If yes , how ?

This is what I tried :

```
$rails c test
>require "./spec/spec_helper"
true
>source = double('source')
NoMethodError: undefined method `double' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to `require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'`, as [stated in the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/outside-rspec/standalone).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails c
```

Comment: That is equivalent to "rails c test" , I believe ?

Comment: Unfortunately not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668167/rails-console-test-loading-development-environment